# Matlab indexing two dimensions with linear indicies while keeping a third dimension constant

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, indexing

Say I have 2D linear indicies:

```
linInd = sub2ind(imSize,rowPnts,colPnts);
```

And I have a 3D color image I:

```
I = rand(64,64,3)*255
```

Is there any way that I can index something like this in order to get all coordinates in the 2D plane but for each channel of the image?  That is, can I get all of the color channel information for each pixel with one command using linear indicies that are specified for 2D?

```
I(linInd,:)
```

So I don't have to split up the image into 3 parts and then reassemble again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`broadcast`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html) the `2D` linear indices to a `3D` case using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) without messing with the input array, like so -

```
[m,n,r] = size(I);
out = I(bsxfun(@plus,linInd,(m*n*(0:r-1))'))
```

---

**Sample setup**

```
%// ---------------- 2D Case ---------------------
im = randi(9,10,10);
imSize = size(im);

rowPnts = [3,6,8,4];
colPnts = [6,3,8,5];
linInd = sub2ind(imSize,rowPnts,colPnts);

%// ---------------- 3D Case ---------------------
I = randi(9,10,10,4);

%// BSXFUN solution
[m,n,r] = size(I);
out = I(bsxfun(@plus,linInd,(m*n*(0:r-1))')); %//'

%// Tedious work of splitting
Ir = I(:,:,1);
Ig = I(:,:,2);
Ib = I(:,:,3);
Ia = I(:,:,4);
```

**Output**

```
>> Ir(linInd)
ans =
     8     9     1     6
>> Ig(linInd)
ans =
     1     5     9     8
>> Ib(linInd)
ans =
     8     5     3     8
>> Ia(linInd)
ans =
     8     8     3     3
>> out
out =
     8     9     1     6
     1     5     9     8
     8     5     3     8
     8     8     3     3
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, reshaping the matrix first is the only way to use linear indexing this way.

```
I2=reshape(I,[],3)
I2(ind,:)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it specifically necessary for you to keep that dimension as the third? If not, you could `permute` the array to move that dimension to the 1st position, then use `arr(i3d, linInd)`.